I'm getting an error while resizing the image
IDE: Pycharm
Error occurred:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4155: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inv_scale_x > 0 in function 'cv::resize'

Code runned:
imgShirt = cv2.resize(imgShirt,(widthOfShirt, int(widthOfShirt*shirtRatioHeightWidth)))    # This line caused the error

Resizing of the image of a tshirt.

what is the value of widthOfShirt and shirtRatioHeightWidth? please post  a minimal reproducible example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
